# Debugging NuGet Gallery Locally does not work when calling from VS instance

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging, nugetgallery

I'm working on setting up my own instance of NuGet Gallery and adding Basic Authentication to the download piece. I've got that mostly sorted out, but I'm running into something I can't explain.

When I hit the api/v2/package download URL from a browser I hit all the breakpoints I would expect to hit. However, when I open up another instance of Visual Studio and set my NuGet sources to only point to my local instance of NuGet Gallery and use the NuGet Package Manager UI, the NuGet package downloads without hitting any of the break points. I have break points all over the place and I would expect the same behavior from the debugging session whether I call the URL from the browser or whether I use the NPM UI in Visual Studio.

Anyone have any ideas on what's causing this behavior?

Comment: I’m a little confused about your issue, are the breakpoints you mentioned, the breakpoints set in a normal Visual Studio project(maybe your NuGet package related project) for debugging? Or you mean the “break”(related to the authentication) while downloading the NuGet package? I guess you mean the second one, perhaps the authentications/credentials are saved by accident, please have a try to remove the related NuGet Credentials in Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager.

Comment: The credentials *should* come from the global nuget.config in the %APPDATA%/nuget directory. 

I have the Nuget Gallery source code running in Debug in Visual Studio instance 1. I open up a console app in Visual Studio instance 2. When I use the nuget package UI to download a nuget package, it doesn't hit ANY breakpoints, related to authentication or not. When I navigate the API download URL in a browser it his break points as expected.

Comment: If you use command(Install-Package XXXX) to install NuGet Package in VS’s Package Manager Console, does it hit breakpoints?